# laravel - send a selected field to with function

Tags: laravel, select, laravel-5, eloquent

how can i use "airpot_id" in with function?

```
    City::select([
                "cities.id",
                "airports.id As airport_id"
            ])
  ->RightJoin('airports', function ($join)
                {
                    $join->on('cities.id', '=', 'airports.city_id');
                })
->with(["airports" =>  function  ($q)
                {
                    $q->where("id",airport_id) //I want to use here.

                }]) 
->paginate(env("PER_PAGE", 10))->toArray();
```

Comment: Can you explain the goal of this query in a sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using joints like this? Use the eloquent query builder. Maybe you should post you `modal`, `relations` and your objective.  In general, if we need to pass value inside function we use `use($variable)`. Something like this

```
$airport_id = 1;
$data = City::with(["airports" =>  function  ($q) use($airport_id){   //Like this we pass data
                    $q->where("id",airport_id)
                }])->get();
```

I don't think this will work in your case

Comment: I don't have a $airport_id variable, per row airport_id send inside query.

Comment: Yes, that is why I said this will not work. Thus you should share you modal and relations